# horizontal recycler view inside vertical recycler View inside a fragment with onactivityResult

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a 'Fragment' which has a vertical `RecyclerView`, inside every item of the `RecyclerView` there is a horizontal`RecyclerView` with an add button. On clicking the Add button `startActivityOnResult` is called. The values on the `onActivityResult` have to update the horizontal `RecyclerView`in the particular view where I clicked add button.

I have achieved almost everything but what's happening is when I update the horizontal `RecyclerView`, all the vertical view items horizontal `RecyclerView`is getting updated.

In Fragment

```
private void displayUpcomingEvents(View view) {
    upcomingEventsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    upcomingEvents = new UpcomingEvents("Meet and greet", "Coffee Connect | ", "Phython", "21 - ", "Jun   ", "22", "  Jun", "21 Jun 10 AM", "Washinton");
    upcomingEventsArrayList.add(upcomingEvents);
    upcomingEvents = new UpcomingEvents("Meet and greet", "Coffee Connect | ", "Phython", "21 - ", "Jun   ", "22", "  Jun", "21 Jun 10 AM", "Washinton");
    upcomingEventsArrayList.add(upcomingEvents);
    upcomingEvents = new UpcomingEvents("Meet and greet", "Coffee Connect | ", "Phython", "21 - ", "Jun   ", "22", "  Jun", "21 Jun 10 AM", "Washinton");
    upcomingEventsArrayList.add(upcomingEvents);
    upcomingEventsAdapter = new RecyclerAdapterUpcomingEvents(getContext(), upcomingEventsArrayList);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_upcoming_event);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getAppContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(upcomingEventsAdapter);

}
```

And in adapter obBindViewHolder

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        UpcomingEvents upcomingEvents = upcomingEventsList.get(position);

        holder.eventUpcomingName.setText(upcomingEvents.getEventUpcomingName());
        holder.eventUpcomingType.setText(upcomingEvents.getEventUpcomingType());

        holder.eventUpcomingDate.setText(dateStartUpcomeEvent + " - " + dateEndUpcomeEvent);
        holder.eventUpcomingMonth.setText(monthStartUpcomeEvent + "    " + monthEndUpcomeEvent);

        holder.eventUpcomingAlarmNotify.setText(dateTimeUpcomeEvent +" to " +dateTimeEndUpcomeEvent);
        holder.eventUpcomingPlace.setText(upcomingEvents.getEventUpcomingPlace());

        holder.eventUpcomingAddPeople.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity origin = (Activity) context;
                Intent i = new Intent(getAppContext(), ContactsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("selectedPosition", position);
                Log.e("tag", "position==> " + position);
                origin.startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_CODE);
            }
        });

        holder.contactRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(getAppContext(), R.layout.card__contact_image, contactsList);
        holder.contactRecyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

    }
```

In fragment how should i receive this data please

[image: This is what i want]

OnActivity Result

```
        int result = data.getIntExtra("selectedPosition", -1);
        contactsLists = (ArrayList<Contact>) data.getSerializableExtra("contacts");
        for (int i = 0; i < contactsLists.size(); i++) {
            Contact contact = contactsLists.get(i);

            if (!otherUserKey.contains(contact.getId())) {
                otherUserKey.add(contact.getId());
                contactsList.add(contact);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Already exits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        contactAdapterMyEvents.setContactList(contactsList);
        myEventsAdapter.notifyItemChanged(result);
```

Comment: can you post your code .

Comment: This should't happen. It should modify the respective adapter. Post your code.

Comment: Updated the code @ChetanJoshi

Comment: Can you provide me some code @Ritesh

Comment: where you are calling `displayUpcomingEvents`? if in view, update that code also

Comment: @ANITHASUNDARAMURTHY, Add your onActivityResult  code.

Comment: can You please take alook at the updated code @MuthukrishnanRajendran