# Log sqlite selected values

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have select query like this

```
 String innerSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_EVENT_TYPE_MASTER + " WHERE EventTypeKey = '" + cursor.getInt(2) + "'";

            Cursor innerCursor = db.rawQuery(innerSelectQuery, null);
            if (innerCursor.moveToFirst()) {

                userEvent.setEventTypeKey(innerCursor.getString(1));
                Log.e("tag", "EventTypeKey " + innerCursor.getString(1));
                innerCursor.close();

            }
```

I was able to log the values using **innerCursor.getString(1)**.Is there a way to log and see the returned values in a table format like sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show full output of your `cursor` use following.

```
Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009786/horizontal-recycler-view-inside-vertical-recycler-view-inside-a-fragment         Can you please take a look at this too ,,

Answer (score 1):

```
Log.d("TAG", "Your Message : " + innerCursor.getString(1));
```

i hope it's helpful to you ..!